# Prevent Ubuntu from recognizing phone as mobile broadband

Tags: internet, mobile-broadband, smartphone

The WiFi module in my laptop is currently broken and in the meantime I tried to use my phone as a WiFi module. I connect my phone to a WiFi (mobile data is disabled) and plug in my phone to the laptop via USB.

Then I turned on USB tethering. For a while Ubuntu recognizes it as ethernet and internet works. After some time it changes to mobile broadband and internet stops working.

How do I prevent Ubuntu from changing the connection type to mobile broadband?
My phone is a LG-G3.

Comment: Switch it in the phone in USB connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I'm still facing this issue every time Ubuntu version is upgraded and I always end up in this same place.

The solution for me is to completely remove the modem manager.

```
apt remove modemmanager
```

After that, turn off and on the USB tethering in the phone and it started to work always as USB Ethernet connection.